# MVC 5 Template for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-5

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2017. I want to create a ASP.NET web application with MVC5. But I can see only MVC 4. I am not able to find any MVC5 Template.

I tried to find one in NuGet package manager and I can't.

Any suggestions how to get that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In VS 2017, **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3** is already in built. You can safely ignore the MVC4 templates display while creating the project. They actually are actually MVC5.